# Window is not releasing when switching to another window

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nswindowcontroller

I am creating a Mac application in which I have mainwindow with some buttons.

When I click button it will open a `DetailWindow` with NSTableview. Every **buttonclickevent** change the data in NSTableView.

Here is my code:

In my **mainWindow.m** FIle

```
- (IBAction)btn1Event:(id)sender {
    if (!detailwindow) {
        detailwindow = [[DetailWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DetailWindow"];
        detailwindow.mainwindow = self;
    }

    detailwindow.title = @"First";
    [detailwindow showWindow:self];
}

- (IBAction)btn2Event:(id)sender{
    if (!detailwindow) {
        detailwindow = [[DetailWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DetailWindow"];
        detailwindow.mainwindow = self;
    }

    detailwindow.title = @"Second";
    [detailwindow showWindow:self];
}
```

In **DetailWindow**

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
     [super windowDidLoad];
     [tableView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
     [tableView setHeaderView:nil];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"First"]){
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"MS.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"CVS.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"NS.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"EM.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"RES.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];
    }

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"Second"]) {
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"RS.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"FB.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]] ;
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"GT.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"SKIN.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];
        [arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"GP.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)GoToMainWindow:(id)sender {
    [mainwindow showWindow:self];
}
```

If i click first button this `if([title isEqualToString:@"First"])` event call and I can see first five image in my tableview.

After that if I click second button I can't see the next five image in table. Data is not changing because `if ([title isEqualToString:@"Second"])` this event is not being call.
If I first click `second` button then same thing happen with `first event`.

Any idea why? I think window is not releasing when I click any of button at secondly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's because your insert image method is in the -(void)windowDidLoad method, which gets called on when the window is loaded, not when you call the showWindow: method so it only gets called once.  Instead of calling the showWindow: method in mainWindow.m, create a new method in DetailWindow instead and call that when you click the button.

```
- (IBAction)btn1Event:(id)sender {

if (!detailwindow) {
    detailwindow = [[DetailWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DetailWindow"];
    detailwindow.mainwindow = self;

}
detailwindow.title = @"First";
[detailwindow addImageToTableView]; //It doesn't have to be named like that.  Your choice
}

- (IBAction)btn2Event:(id)sender{

if (!detailwindow) {
    detailwindow = [[DetailWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"DetailWindow"];
    detailwindow.mainwindow = self;
}
detailwindow.title = @"Second";
[detailwindow addImageToTableView];

//DetailWindow

- (void)addImageToTableView
{
 [super windowDidLoad];
 [tableView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
 [tableView setHeaderView:nil];

if([title isEqualToString:@"First"]){

[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"MS.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"CVS.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"NS.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"EM.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"RES.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];

}

if ([title isEqualToString:@"Second"]) {

[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"RS.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"FB.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]] ;
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"GT.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"SKIN.png"],@"image",@"first image",@"text", nil]];
[arrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:@"GP.png"],@"image",@"second image",@"text", nil]];

}
[tableView reloadData];
}
- (IBAction)GoToMainWindow:(id)sender {

[mainwindow showWindow:self];

}
```

It's definitely not the best code you should have.  Just make some changes to the code above and it should be sufficient.

Comment: First of all thank u so much theAmateurProgrammer..!! I have tried this code. This time both events are calling when i click button , but **images are not changing in table**. they remain same. and i think i have to call `[detailwindow showWindow:self];` if i want detailWindow by click event.. Am i ryt??

Comment: Oh.  You want to "change" it instead of adding data do you?  Then remove all of the data in arrayController by using removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes: to remove the objects then add the Object and the data should change.

Comment: Ok i notice one thing.. If i click on first button and then second button it adds its all 5 image below the existed image(first button's image). so i get all 10 images in second click.. Any help??

Comment: Thats the thing.  You're "adding" images to it without taking the images away from it.  Essentially, you have 5.  You want a different 5, however, you're not taking away the original 5 so you end up with 10.  Which is why you gotta use the [arrayController removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:5]]; before you actually have the addObject methods.

Comment: I put `[arrayController removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:5]];` in `if ([title isEqualToString:@"Second"]) ` above `addObject`. Still it is adding image.. I am really new to mac development.. so giving u that much trouble.. :(

Comment: You would want to put that before the first if.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3787/discussion-between-theamateurprogrammer-and-snhl)

Comment: one thing.. :P  My number of addObjects are not fix.. so is there any way to remove all objects from array when we click another button for adding new objects??